# Passing user inputted text through jQuery Ajax and then outputting results to user

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework, input

I need help understanding the proper sequence of filtering data when sending user inputted comments through ajax.

My input textarea data is filtered like so

```
   $comment  = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['comment']));
```

And I input that into the database. I need it to simply be safe text that displays symbosl. Now I need to show this content to a member with all the slashes they put in, in their comment.

I don't want to see

```
    The comment\'s not so pleasant to read.
```

I don't know how to google this question.. or formulate the sentence. I wish to be able to return a nicely formatted comment using ajax aswell. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I just wish not to be hacked :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to strip the slashes before printing?

```
echo stripslashes($str);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I do that with pages that require to reload the page. If I use an ajax request to send me the data though, it comes out with the slashes and I can't find a way to strip slashes unless I use a dirty javascript method. I thought maybe there's a clean way with least amount of programming.

Comment: ajax only returns what the server sends to the callback. If the server is stripping the slashes it should come without it. Inspect your request and return and see if it has slashes there. If yes then the server adds slashes that need to be stripped right before printing. I doubt it's the client...

Comment: use stripslashes in the ajax page itself